# showNoCameraAlert error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a flashlight app. In my code, if camera(hardware) is there, it should show an alert, but it does not show the alert. My code is as below:

```
if (!isCameraFlash) {
        showNoCameraAlert();
    } else {
        camera = Camera.open();
        params = camera.getParameters();
    }
```

but i get an error on

```
showNoCameraAlert();
```

Is this an invalid tag? or the tutorial i am using is old? I am using android studio. Here is my full Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Camera camera;
    ImageButton flashlightSwitchImg;
    private boolean isFlashlightOn;
    Parameters params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flashlightSwitchImg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashlightSwitch);
        boolean isCameraFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if (!isCameraFlash) {
            showNoCameraAlert();
        } else {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: What's the error? Can you share the log? Also we need to see how `showNoCameraAlert()` method is implemented. I assume you already implemented it some way, because is not a native method.

Comment: Maybe i can help you, i used the same tutorial for my flashlight app :-). What's the code off `showNoCameraAlert()`?

Comment: @joaquin It says cannot resolve method showNoCameraMethod

Comment: Please post your FULL code. Especially `showNoCameraAlert()`

Comment: I posted, i just coded till here. @superthomaslab

Comment: @AkhileshKumar I added an answer, this should help you

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `showNoCameraAlert()` method. You need to add it to your `MainActivity` (that is the file where you put the code in.) So add it like this:

```
private void showNoCameraAlert(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera flashlight not available in this Android device!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The full code for your `MainActivity`:

```
package com.example.administrator.flashlight;

import ...;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Camera camera;
    ImageButton flashlightSwitchImg;
    private boolean isFlashlightOn;
    Parameters params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flashlightSwitchImg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashlightSwitch);
        //check if phone has a flashlight
        boolean isCameraFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()    .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)

        if (!isCameraFlash) {
            //show error ( showNoCamereAlert() is below)
            showNoCameraAlert();
        } else {
            //open the camera
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        }
    }

    private void showNoCameraAlert(){
        //Show Error toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera flashlight not available in this Android device!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: What? MainActivity.xml?

Comment: @joaquin Oops, fixed it ;-)

Comment: I suppossed it! You were meaning `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Who is downvoting my answer. This answer did answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm starting to think that you didn't implement the `showNoCameraAlert()` method.

Try adding something like this to your `MainActivity` class:

```
private void showNoCameraAlert(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There's no camera on the device or it doesn't have a flash", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: As in eclipse, i used Ctrl+o. what should i use in android studio?

Comment: Do you have at least the basics on coding?

Comment: I am veryyyy new. Understand please. and by the way i am only 13